# Jackson LocalDate nonexisting date

Tags: java, jackson

Consider the following example class:

```
public class TheDto {
    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyMMdd", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
    private Date date;
    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyMMdd", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
    private LocalDate localDate;
}
```

For same input, "180231", `date` field fails to parse, since 31. February doesn't exist.
But, `localDate` succeeds with value of "180228".
Is there a way to enforce `LocalDate` `lenient=false`, to strictly validate date existence?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863873/jackson-accepting-negative-dates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard whenever possible, which is endorsed by the [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) and also by the [xkcd 1179](https://xkcd.com/1179/) :)

---

If such standard is not an option for your application, you could create your own deserializer, where you specify your own [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with a [`ResolverStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html) that can be [`LENIENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#LENIENT), [`SMART`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART) or [`STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT):

```java
public class CustomLocalDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyMMdd")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.ERA, 1)
            .toFormatter()
            .withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE)
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT); // Also can be LENIENT or SMART

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser p,
                                 DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

        String value = p.getValueAsString();
        return LocalDate.parse(value, FORMATTER);
    }
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```java
public class Foo {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate date;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
String json = "{\"date\":\"180231\"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
```

---

Consider `yyMMdd` as the date format and `180231` as the input. You'll have different results according to the [`ResolverStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html):

- [`LENIENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#LENIENT): The value of `date` will be `2018-03-03`.
- [`SMART`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART): The value of `date` will be `2018-02-28`.
- [`STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT): An exception will be thrown: `Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31'`.